# Keras CNN overfitting for more than four classes

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to train a classifier on [Google QuickDraw](https://quickdraw.withgoogle.com/) drawings using [Keras](https://keras.io):

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Dense, Flatten, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=5, data_format="channels_last", activation="relu", input_shape=(28, 28, 1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(data_format="channels_last"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=3, data_format="channels_last", activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(data_format="channels_last"))

model.add(Flatten(data_format="channels_last"))

model.add(Dense(units=128, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(units=64, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(units=4, activation="softmax"))

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

x = np.load("./x.npy")
y = np.load("./y.npy")

model.fit(x=x, y=y, batch_size=100, epochs=40, validation_split=0.2)
```

The input data is a 4d array with 12000 normalized images (28 x 28 x 1) per class. The output data is an array of one hot encoded vectors.

If I train this model on four classes, it produces convincing results:

[image: loss 4 classes]
[image: accuracy 4 classes]

(red is training data, blue is validation data)

I know the model is slightly overfitted. However, I want to keep the architecture as simple as possible, so I accepted that.

My problem is that as soon as I add just one arbitrary class, the model starts to overfit extremely:

[image: loss 5 classes]
[image: accuracy 5 classes]

I tried many different things to prevent it from overfitting such as Batch Normalization, Dropout, Kernel Regularizers, much more training data and different batch sizes, none of which caused any significant improvement.

What could be the reason why my CNN overfits so much?

---

**EDIT:** This is the code I used to create `x.npy` and `y.npy`:

```
import numpy as np

from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical

files = ['cat.npy', 'dog.npy', 'apple.npy', 'banana.npy', 'flower.npy']

SAMPLES = 12000

x = np.concatenate([np.load(f'./data/{f}')[:SAMPLES] for f in files]) / 255.0
y = np.concatenate([np.full(SAMPLES, i) for i in range(len(files))])

# (samples, rows, cols, channels)
x = x.reshape(x.shape[0], 28, 28, 1).astype('float32')
y = to_categorical(y)

np.save('./x.npy', x)
np.save('./y.npy', y)
```

The `.npy` files come from [here](https://github.com/googlecreativelab/quickdraw-dataset#numpy-bitmaps-npy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies with how the data split is done. Notice that there are 5 classes and you do `0.2` validation split. By default there's no shuffling and in your code you feed the data in a sequential order. What that means:

- Training data consists entirely of 4 classes: 'cat.npy', 'dog.npy', 'apple.npy', 'banana.npy'. That's the `0.8` training split.
- Test data is 'flower.npy'. That's your `0.2` validation split. The model was never trained on this so it gets terrible accuracy.

Such results are only possible thanks to the fact that the `validation_split=0.2`, so you get close to perfect class separation.

**Solution**

```
x = np.load("./x.npy")
y = np.load("./y.npy")

# Shuffle the data!
p = np.random.permutation(len(x))
x = x[p]
y = y[p]

model.fit(x=x, y=y, batch_size=100, epochs=40, validation_split=0.2)
```

if my hypothesis is correct, setting the `validation_split` to e.g. `0.5` should also get you much better results (though it's not a solution).

Comment: *"in case of four classes you're already oiverfitting severely"* - If you just look at the first few (5) epochs, you can see pretty decent curves. I ran the training process multiple times and the model always reaches an accuracy >90%. The best result I got was 95% after 6 epochs, which is more than enough for my use case and I'm content with that.

Comment: *"Drop the dense_1; Add more convnet with 3x3 kernel; 5x5 kernel is quite large, consider making it smaller; Consider removing pooling layers completely."* - I've tried all of this, none of it has improved anything.

Comment: *"Consider removing intermediate dense layers completely."* - What do you mean *intermediate dense layers*?

Comment: *"Can you paste your code for it?"* - I've used the exact same model (except for an extra output neuron). - *"It's close to impossible."* - That's exactly what makes me puzzled, too. That's why I have asked here, in the hope that someone would have an idea as to what the problem might be.

Comment: @Scriptim which is exactly why I am asking to paste the exact code. However minor difference seems to be it's primary suspect. Maybe paste a gist?

Comment: I guarantee you the above code is the exact code. For the second model I only changed `units=4` to `units=5`. I've now added the code to the question that I used to create the numpy arrays, since the data is the second factor that changes with an additional class. Maybe the issue is there somewhere.

Comment: @Scriptim Thanks! I have a hypothesis on what could be the issue. Please check the edits.

Comment: Thank you so much, that solved the problem! Keras shuffles the data by default during the training process however the validation split is done before the shuffling. (https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit)